# Google Play Console : Provide instructions for app access

Tags: google-play, google-play-services, google-play-console, android-app-bundle, android-app-signing

I have developed an app that is using Auth APIs of Facebook and Gmail. as you know we don't need any email password to login just click on facebook or gmail button and auth API generates authentication token to login into app.

So I am submitting that app on playstore but they are rejecting and asking for login credentials. I have provided them my gmail account login credentials but they using those credentials to login into facebook account and rejected my app again.

what I should do to avoid rejection again?

Comment: You gave your own gmail login & password to someone? Doesn't sound like something you should be doing...

Comment: I have given that because they were asking, but still they rejected my app

Comment: ...nobody from Google should be asking for your credentials, and you shouldn't be giving them to _anybody_, under _any circumstances_. I suggest you change them _immediately_ and then go through your history data to see what they have been doing.

Comment: Were you able to publish the app? Please let me what did you update to the team if it gets accepted. In my app I only have Gmail signup/login but they are rejecting as I haven't provided any credentials.